# Integrating the log-normal function

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, statistics, definite-integrals

Compute
$$F(t)=\int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma t} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\log t-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right]\,dt; t>0$$

#### My Attempt:

$u=\frac{1}{t}\Rightarrow du=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt$

and

$$dv=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\log t-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] \, dt\Rightarrow v=\text{ ?}$$

Integration by parts formula :
$$\int u \, dv=uv-\int v \, du$$

Comment: I'd start with $u = \log t$ so that $du = \dfrac{dt}t$.  Notice that you actually do multiply everything by $\dfrac{dt}t$ within the integral. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Try u = ln t so du = 1/t dt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is at best somewhat infelicitous to use the same letter as the argument to $F$ and the bound variable of integration, so I'll write this as
$$
F(t)=\int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\sigma} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\log s-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right]\,\frac{ds} s; \qquad t>0
$$
Let $u=\log s$ so that $du=\dfrac{ds}s$; then
$$
F(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\log t} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi} \, \sigma} \exp\left[ -\frac 1 2 \left(\frac{u-\mu} \sigma \right)^2 \right] \, du.
$$
This is $\Phi(\log t)$, where $\Phi$ is a function that notoriously lacks a closed-form expression, but its values are tabulated in an appendix to most elementary statistics textbooks.  One has
$$
\Phi'(t) = \varphi(t) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2}.
$$
The graph of the derivative $\varphi$ is the celebrated "bell-shaped curve".

Comment: Well, it's the standard normal distribution function after you standardise it to have mean $0$ and variance $1$...